# Java RSA decryption did not work for the data decrypted with its public key in IPhone

Tags: java, iphone, encryption, rsa

Hi I have created my rsa public key in java and send to my friend.
My friend is using IPhone, he encrypted data with that key and send me the decrypted data then I decrypted the data with my private key.
But I am getting errors for Bad Padding.
I and my friend both did  not use any padding explicitly for RSA.

Thanks
Bapi

Comment: Consider posting code. This may help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

your question is unclear
it was decrypted twice?

editing for your edit:
you're still wrong, you may want to read up on how public key cryptography works before asking questions about your specific implementation. it sounds like you are very unfamiliar with the process